# Dominated Convergence Theorem when Integrand is a Stochastic Process

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

So I have a sequence of estimators $\phi_n$ that converges almost surely to $\phi^*$. These estimators are used to parametrise a function $f_{\phi_n}(x)$ which thus forms a random process to be integrated:

$I_n= \int_X f_{\phi_n}(x) dp(x)$.

Now, I can show that there exists a real $M$ such that $\vert f_{\phi}(x)\vert \le M$ for all $x\in X$ and $\phi\in\Phi$. As $f$ is continuous in $\phi$, I have $f_{\phi_n}(x)\xrightarrow{N\rightarrow\infty}f_{\phi^*}(x)$ almost surely. Can I apply an analogue of the dominated convergence theorem, i.e something like

$I_n\xrightarrow{N\rightarrow\infty} \int_X f_{\phi^*}(x) dp(x)$ almost surely?

Comment: Simply apply the dominated convergence theorem to $\int_X f_{\phi_n(\omega)}(x) \, dp(x)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Stochastic Integration can be build entirely on the idea that this property of "dominated convergence" must be present in any "good" integration operator (this property can be viewed in some sense as a continuity property for the integration operator). This is the approach followed by Protter in his book "Stochastic integration and differential equations". Regards